# plotly add-in for powerpoint, how to embed local plots

Tags: powerpoint, plotly

I have the plotly add-in from here

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104379485?tab=Overview

It works on the sample link. But for work it's certainly not ok to upload my data online. Is it possible to embed the local html files I generated in python with plotly.offline.plot?

Or if there is some other way to embed plotly charts in ppt, I'm happy to take it as well.